# Why does a static electric shock touching my printer make my computer screen to tremble for 1/2 second?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, voltage

I work in an office that has a problem with its floor so we are permanently giving static electric shocks to everything. When this happens with my printer, my computer screen trembles a little bit. I was wondering that it probably is because I create an anomaly in the voltage balance of the office's electricity grid, but I can't believe that that small amount of energy can affect my office's electrical grid.

Comment: Is the printer's connection to your computer wireless, or is there a cable?

Comment: @D.Ennis it is connected to a network via ethernet

Comment: Is this a CRT (vacuum tube) monitor or the newer LCD type?

Comment: It is a 5 years old LCD screen

Answer (score 1):

It would also cause an electric field, that the comupter screen hears.

It would be more a cause of electricity in the air.  I would reccomend getting some kind of earthing pad to touch before using the computer, if static is a serious problem.